# Increase the selectable area around text

Tags: javascript, css

I am creating a feature to search text that a user highlights on our page. For example, the UI might have a paragraph of text and a user will highlight a word which will automatically kick off a search for that word. Currently they have to highlight exactly on the text in order to capture/search the term. The desired effect is to increase the "selectable" area around the text so the user doesn't have to so exact.

For example, the blue area is the only area that the user can highlight to capture "dolor" 
[(current selectable area)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cy3oB.png)
but I would like it to be a little more lenient [(enhanced selectable area)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GX4nN.jpg) where if the user started selecting like in the enhanced picture, they would get "dolor" and not the word underneath.

I have already tried modifying the margin and padding around the word (`{padding: 10px; margin -10px`):

[image]

but it doesn't affect the "selectable" area and starting the selection in the green area still captures the word underneath.

The current css for the paragraph:

```
paragraph {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

And for the individual text divs:

```
text-div {
  font-size: 1.25em;
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

I suspect the line-height is what's making this difficult, but I would like to keep the look of the UI as is. Is there any javascript or css way I can achieve this?

**UPDATE:**

For clarification, here is a more exaggerated view:

[image]

As a user I would expect to be capturing dolor, but when I start selecting where the cursor is in the picture, it selects the line below.

Comment: But what if they wanted to select the text underneath and it selected "dolor" instead? Would seem very frustrating to me as a user.

Comment: I guess I am trying to "evenly" divide the whitespace so that the upper half between the two paragraph lines would select the top line but right now it is grabbing the bottom line. I added an exaggerated picture to my original post

Comment: Not sure if the effect you're trying to achieve is even possible with pure css. Do you mind inclusion of JS code in the solution?

Comment: Not at all, I was expecting that I would need to address this using JS

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of padding with negative margin you can achieve what you're looking for if I understand the question correctly. I've added a hover state so you can see the selectable area in the snippet. The area is a little exaggerated here for example purposes, but you could alter that to your needs.

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
.text-div {
  font-weight:bold;
  padding: 2rem;
  margin: -2rem;
}

.text-div:hover {
  background-color: rgba(100,100,100,.5);
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum et <span class='text-div'>dolor mauris</span>. Proin tempus eros est, cursus consectetur ante accumsan ut. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Quisque in metus in metus pellentesque molestie eu vel lectus. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque egestas accumsan sapien eget consequat. Cras porttitor enim eget tellus semper ornare.
</p>
```

Comment: Unfortunately I've tried that and it works if it's to increase the area for a clickable link but it hasn't solved the highlight/select issue. (I added a clarification photo to my original post if that helps).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this issue by adding

```
vertical-align:middle
```

to the CSS for the text elements. It moved the text to the middle of the line and the top/bottom spacing was evenly distributed which allowed for increased "selectability".